# Vertical lines on laptop screen

Tags: laptop, display

Two vertical lines appeared on laptop screen while working. They appear in BIOS screen too so it is not a driver's issue. I tried restarting, draining the power etc. but the issue persists.
Is there any solution to this problem?[image]

Comment: The solution is replacing the screen panel.

Comment: Try the monitor with another PC. If the lines persist, time to get a new monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the lines are still displaying in the BIOS settings, it may be
a hardware failure.

In this situation, the only operation you can on software
(firmware really) is to perform a BIOS/EFI update from the
manufacturer's website.
Take good backups and read about doing so safely.
Ensure that the operation cannot be interrupted by power failure
and such.

If updating the BIOS doesn't change anything, it's time to replace
the screen.
If you don't have experience with such operations, it's better
for it to be done by a professional, since it's a delicate operation
and it's too easy to break something.

Comment: I updated BIOS but in vain